# Encoding abstract keyword semantic in Alloy by constraints

Tags: encoding, abstract, alloy

I would like to encode the **abstract** keyword semantic as a constraint in Alloy (be patient, I need to do this for a reason! :) ). if I have the following code:

```
abstract sig A {}
sig a1 extends A{}
sig a2 extends A{}
```

I think its meaning would be as following (I hope I am right!):

```
sig A {}
sig a1 in A{}
sig a2 in A{}

fact {
   A=a1+a2         //A is nothing other than a1 and a2
   a1 & a2 = none  // a1 and a1 are disjoint
}
```

so the two above signatures are equal (i.e., would be semantically equal):

I am eager to use the Abstract keyword that Alloy provide to make life easy, But the problem arises when I make A to be a subset of sig O and use **abstract** keyword:

```
sig O{}
abstract sig A in O{}
sig a1 extends A{}
sig a2 extends A{}
```

above syntax returns an error! Alloy complains:"Subset signature cannot be abstract.", so my first question is : **Why Alloy does not allow this?**

I don't stop and encode abstract keyword semantic (as explained above) , and come to the following code:

```
sig O{}
sig A in O{}
sig a1 in A{}
sig a2 in A{}

fact {
    A=a1+a2             // A can not be independently instantiated
    a1 & a2 = none      // a1 and a2 are disjoint
}
```

And this works, and everything is fine :)

Now if I want to add a3 to my Alloy specification, I need to tweak my specification as the following:

```
sig O{}
sig A in O{}
sig a1 in A{}
sig a2 in A{}
sig a3 in A{}

fact {
    A=a1+a2+3           
    a1 & a2 = none  
    a1 & a3 = none
    a2 & a3 = none
}
```

But as you see by comparing the two specification above, if I want to continue this, and add a4 in a similar way to my specification, I need to change the fact part even more, and this continues to be hassle! Actually the number of ai & aj =none (for i=1..n) expressions are increasing non-monotonously! i.e., adding a4 force me to add more than one constraint:

```
fact {
    A=a1+a2+3 +a4           
    a1 & a2 = none  
    a1 & a3 = none
    a1 & a4 = none
    a2 & a3 = none
    a2 & a4 = none
    a3 & a4 = none

}
```

So my second question:
**Is there any workaround (or probably simpler way) to do this?**

Any comment is appreciated.
Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

On Q1 (why does Alloy not allow extension of subset signatures?):  I don't know.

On Q2 (is there a workaround):  the simplest workaround is to make a1 ... an be subsignatures (extensions) of A, and find another way to establish the relation of A and O.  In the simple examples you have given, O has no subtypes so simply changing `A in O` to `A extends O` would work.

If O is already partitioned by other signatures you haven't shown us, then that workaround doesn't work; it's impossible to say what would work without more detail.  (Ideally, you want a minimum complete working example to illustrate the difficulty:  the examples you give are minimal, and illustrate one difficulty, but they don't illustrate why A cannot be an extension of O.)

---

[Addendum]

In a comment, you say

> The reason [that I used *A in O* instead of *A extends O*] is that there is another signature C in O that is not shown here. A and C are not necessarily disjoint, so that is the reason I think I have to use **in** instead of **extend** in defining them to be subset of O.

The devil is in the details, but the conclusion doesn't follow from the premises stated.  If A and C both extend O, they will be disjoint, but if one uses **extend** and the other uses **in** they are not automatically disjoint.  So if you want to have A and C each be a subset of O, and A to be partitioned by several other signatures, it is possible to do so (unless there are other constraints not yet mentioned).

```
sig O {}
abstract sig A extends O {}
sig a1, a2 extends A {}
sig a3, a4 extends A {}
sig C in O {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right, there is a reason that I used _A in O_ instead of _A extends O_ ! The reason is that there is another signature _C in O_ that is not shown here.  A and C are not necessarily disjoint, so that is the reason I think I have to use **in** instead of **extend** in defining them to be subset of O.